# Insert symbol between letters on certain lines

Tags: ruby, regex

I am manipulating text. I want to put a dot between capital letters on every line except for lines that start with the word `name`. For example:

```
right VGS
flat DASabcdf
foot
foobar asdfsadf. ASDFSADF
name Lorem ipsum dolor.  ASDF
ASDF
```

should become

```
right V.G.S
flat D.A.Sabcdf
foot
foobar asdfsadf. A.S.D.F.S.A.D.F
name Lorem ipsum dolor.  ASDF
A.S.D.F
```

I tried `line.gsub(/(?=[A-Z])(?<=[A-Z])/, ".")`, but it puts a dot between capital letters in all lines. Then I tried `line.gsub(/^(?!name)(.*?)(?=[A-Z])([A-Z]*)(.*$)/, '\1\2.split('').join('.')\3')` but it puts:

```
right VGS.split('').join('')
flat DAS.split('').join('')abcdf
foot
foobar asdfsadf. ASDFSADF.split('').join('')
name Lorem ipsum dolor.  ASDF
ASDF.split('').join('')
```

Comment: The issue is not clear. What is the logic for deleting the period on the fourth line after `asdfsadf`?

Comment: There is no need of deleting dot in the 4th line. I used dot after `asdfsadf` just for showing all possible cases.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you have a Ruby tag and no PHP tag, yet you selected as the best answer one that works with PHP but not with Ruby. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry for missed period in 4th line. I edited my qestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^name\b.*( *SKIP)( *F)|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])
```

You can use `SKIP` and `F` to fail the lines starting `name`.See demo.Replace by `.`

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/27

Comment: Thanks but in your demo regex works for PHP but I am using Ruby. And for make this code valid a have to put **space** before `*SKIP` and `*F`. I now this `^name\b.*( *SKIP)( *F)|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])` exactly want I want.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looping through all the lines in a multiline string and test it for the word `name` in the beginning, and only modify the lines that pass the test:

```
output = ""
str.each_line do |line|
    if !line.start_with?("name")
        output += line.gsub(/(?=[A-Z])(?<=[A-Z])/, ".")
    else
        output += line
    end
end
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/C5q31f)

Comment: Perhaps you can do it slightly simpler with nested `gsub`.

Comment: @sawa: Maybe, I just wanted to show that multiline input can be read line by line so that OP regex could use his own regex with no modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create an input file:

```
str = <<_
right VGS
flat DASabcdf
foot
foobar asdfsadf. ASDFSADF
name Lorem ipsum dolor.  ASDF
ASDF
_

FNameIn =  'text_in'
FNameOut = 'text_out'
IO.write(FNameIn, str)
```

You can do what you want as follows:

```
f = File.open(FNameOut, 'w')
IO.foreach(FNameIn) do |line|
  f.puts(line =~ /^[nN]ame\b/ ? line :
    line.gsub(/[A-Z]{2,}/) { |s| s.split('').join('.') })
end
f.close
```

Let's confirm:

```
puts IO.read(FNameOut)
  #=> right V.G.S
  #   flat D.A.Sabcdf
  #   foot
  #   foobar asdfsadf A.S.D.F.S.A.D.F
  #   name Lorem ipsum dolor.  ASDF
  #   A.S.D.F
```